# Retrieving hidden variable value in Controller

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am setting the hidden variable in the .jsp file using this:

```
<form>
    Select file: <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="app" value="app"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

For retrieving the value of the hidden variable in controller, I used this:
Java Controller class
But unfortunately the value of the `String str` is coming as null which means its not working.

```
final String app = request.getParameter("app");
```

Comment: There is no string variable called `str`.

Comment: Are you sure do you have value in your hidden text box? If so dubug your code in controller.. I hope you need to add action to the form the get the values..

Answer (score 0):

In form there should be an action like for example

```
<form action="test.jsp">
                     Select file: <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="app" value="app"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
             </form>
```

In the test.jsp file you can use `final String app = request.getParameter("app");`
Then you will get the value of `app`
In the action you can also use servlet but you need to configure it properly in the web.xml else you will get only `null`
As per your question in the action you should write the name of the controller

Comment: <form name="upload" action="/push" enctype= "multipart/form-data" method="POST">

Comment: @user2847197 have you configured it properly in the web.xml file?

Comment: Well i have already done action in form basically i have if and else statement in my java controller class if i comment if and else statement my code works but when i am using my code for example if app is .... it shows me null

Answer (score 0):

It should be go to controller not to another jsp page. Hence it may be like this,

```
<form action="Your_controller_name">
                 Select file: <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="app" value="app"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
         </form>
```

Make sure you have this controller name available in web.xml file. Like this

```
 <servlet>
   <display-name>Your_controller_name</display-name>
   <servlet-name>Your_controller_name</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.controller.Your_controller_name</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
```

Comment: Well i have already done action in form basically i have if and else statement in my java controller class if i comment if and else statement my code works but when i am using my code for example if app is .... it shows me null

Comment: Can you post your code in controller? How you are receiving multi-part form data?

Comment: You are storing the value of app in String variable name called **app**, so how will you receive value in  variable str? You need to edit your question for better answers..

Comment: This is my controller:

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        final String app = request.getParameter("app");
        if (app.equals(AI)) { code here }